# compilation error for navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator

I am new in objective C. I don't know much more things about this. I am practicing on navigation controller. The problem is that whatever methods I am putting in action:`@selector` in shows `SIGABRT` error. 
could you clarify me which types of methods i can put in action:`@selector` section.
Though I know it's a silly question but I think these will clear my concept over `navigationViewController`.

thank you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UISearchBar *search=[[UISearchBar alloc] init];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(searchBarShouldBeginEditing:)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    UISearchBar *search=[[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    [search resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your '[super viewDidLoad]' to the beginning of the viewDidLoad method, not the end.  YOu need to make sure the controls exist before you add the right bar button item.